# How to have two variable in a scatter qplot or ggplot2?

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I have two scatter plot :

```
qplot(Date,Min,data=baseSenior,color=Type,facets=Rating~Amount.Outstanding)
qplot(Date,Max,data=baseSenior,color=Type,facets=Rating~Amount.Outstanding)
```

baseSenior is my dataframe, i'd like to obtain one Scatter plot with Max and Min on it. Of course, i want to keep the same sort with Type, Rating and Amount.Outstanding who are categorial variables.

I'm really a newbie with ggplot2, thank you for your time.

Comment: reproducible example??

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide [a subset of your real data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as a part of your question so that other users can follow along what the plots should look like? It would also make the question useful for people who face a similar problem later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to `reshape` your data with `melt()` into one long `data_frame`

```
library(reshape)
M <- melt(baseSenior,id.vars=c("Date","Type","Rating","Amount.Outstanding"),measure.vars=c("Min","Max"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=M,aes(x=Date,y=value,colour=Type,shape=variable)) +
   geom_point() + 
   facet_grid(Rating~Amount.Outstanding)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what i want!